# Customising the generic Rails error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Our rails app is designed as a single code base linking to multiple client databases. Based on the subdomain the app determines which db to connect to.

We use liquid templates to customise the presentation for each client. We are unable to customise the generic 'We're Sorry, somethign went wrong..' message for each client.

Can anyone recommend an approach that would allow us to do this.

Thanks

DOm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For catching exceptions in Rails 2, `rescue_from` controller method is a great way to specify actions which handle various cases.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from MyAppError, :with => :show_errors

  def show_errors
    render :action => "..."
  end
end
```

This way you can make dynamic error pages to replace the static "public/500.html" page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you're trying to do inline error messaging or new page error messaging, but if you want to improve the text around inline error messaging, [this post](http://www.softiesonrails.com/2008/4/23/better-messages-for-activerecord-validation-errors) provides good information.