# error messages in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how do i display error messages in the web browser when using rails?

eg. if i use a variable in the view that i hasn't defined in the controller i want to get an error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller:

```
def your_method
  #processing that fails
  flash[:notice] = 'your error message'
end
```

In your view:

```
<% if !flash[:notice].nil? %>
    <p id="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
<% end %>
```

The documentation for the Flash hash is available [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Flash.html).

To rescue from errors at the application level rather than displaying error messages to the user, you can use

```
  rescue_from ErrorType, :with => :action_method
```

Examples:
[Customising the generic Rails error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101012/customising-the-generic-rails-error-message)
http://www.perfectline.co.uk/blog/custom-dynamic-error-pages-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: i meant more like errors that is generated by rails (maybe the view is using a variable that hasnt been defined)

Comment: fayer. Thanks for the accept even though I didn't answer the question you were looking for.  Your question was short and made it sound like a per-controller exception should be displayed as an error message.  I updated my answer with a couple of references for how to show a customized error page based on exceptions in your controllers.  The second link is a pretty good resource and shows how to catch errors and log, but you'll have to be careful that logging doesn't throw errors or you'll get locked in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you have errors like the mentioned one,  when you try to reach the respective page you should have an error message instead of the proper page.